Briefly stopped at US Border because I read books
I was stopped recently at JFK border because the officer saw that I carried two books in my tote and thought out loud that it was super weird that ppl esp. a young girl still read nowadays. Gave me a long-winded lecture about not wasting my time with meaningless words. I was too scared to shoot back but thankfully he let me go after eliciting a promise that I would burn those books sooner I got to my flat (of course I didn't!) Anyone's experienced anything near this level of ludicrousness? More importantly, shall I file a complaint to the airport?

Obviously I wasn't there, but when you describe it like that, it sounds like a badly judged attempt at humour by officer.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Once I had something similar at the baggage check before departure in Schiphol:

Officer: oh, you are [nationality], are you carrying any [famous liquor from my nation], I really like it.

I just smiled and answered I wasn't carrying any, but if they requested to inspect my baggage I would not oppose.
It can be attempt at humor, it can be a probing technique to see how you react to an "innocent" question, under the assumption that if you are hiding something you would be answering more jumpy on any questioning.
In my experience acting confrontational with border control results at least in additional loss of time before getting clearance.

I suppose that despite your username including the word "Dutch" that [nationality] does not stand for "Dutch."  Because an officer at Schiphol saying, "oh, you are Dutch, do you have any jenever" would be a bit odd.

@phoog - well, yes, because of course they would have some jenever!

@JonCuster i thought it was Genever, like Gin

@Hatman - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenever#:~:text=Jenever%20(English%3A%20%2Fd%CA%92%C9%99,northern%20France%20and%20northwestern%20Germany.

@Hatman according to Dutch Wikipedia, it was genever in middle Dutch, which probably goes a long way toward explaining the variant spellings in modern English.  Since I first encountered it when I was living in Amsterdam, I spell (and pronounce!) it as in modern Dutch.  Gin in fact derives from genever; I wonder when and why Dutch switched back to [y] and  as the standard pronunciation and spelling.
